# When closing, the space occupied by taskbar is blocked and it is not released

Tags: c#, winapi

I am using shellLibrary and creating a custom desktop task bar. When I try to close the task bar using BaseClose(), it closes that perfectly.

But the problem is the space occupied by taskbar is blocked and it is not released. 
I also tried using window handle like FindWindowEX, FindWindow, SendMessage.

I guess even after the taskbar which is a form is closed, the resources are not disposed.

Comment: Do you think, code will help people understand it better?

Comment: @shahkalpesh, what is that..I couldn get wat u said.

Comment: @karthik: I mean that adding code will help people understand things better than describing the problem like the way it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but you are hitting weird bugs because you [cannot write Shell extensions in C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/junfeng/archive/2005/11/18/494572.aspx) - you must use native code.

Comment: Strictly speaking you can write extensions in C#, it just causes so many problems that it's typically advisable not to.

Comment: It's worse than that, it's *guaranteed* to cause problems; they just might not be immediately apparent. It's okay if all you want is a proof-of-concept, but it's throwaway code.

Comment: @Paul, yes I agree.  But to me your answer implies it's not possible which is not true.  It is possible to write a shell extension in C#.  It probably just won't be worth much.

Comment: @JaredPar Shhhh - *I* know that, and *you* know that, but I don't want to give people the impression that it _just_might_ work and have them sink hours of their time into something that will inevitably fail